# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, swift3

I get this error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'" when I try to  get status
>   string into dictionary

My code is:

```
do {         
    let dictionary: Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject> = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: geocodingResultsData!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>

    // Get the response status.

    let status = dictionary["status"] as! String // Here : Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' 

    if status == "OK" {
        let allResults = dictionary["results"] as! Array<Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>>
        self.lookupAddressResults = allResults[0]

        // Keep the most important values.
        self.fetchedFormattedAddress = self.lookupAddressResults["formatted_address"]as! String
        let geometry = self.lookupAddressResults["geometry"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>
        self.fetchedAddressLongitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lng"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue
        self.fetchedAddressLatitude = ((geometry["location"] as! Dictionary<NSObject, AnyObject>)["lat"] as! NSNumber).doubleValue

        completionHandler(status: status, success: true)
    }
    else {
        completionHandler(status: status, success: false)
    }
} catch {
}
```

Comment: Use `[String:Any]` instead of `[NSObject:AnyObject]`. JSON keys are required to be `String`. And omit `mutableContainers`. It's not needed in Swift at all.

Comment: Or try `let status = dictionary["status" as NSObject] as! String`